# LateX Beamer : Putting a tikzpicture next to a picture

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

I'd like to put tikzpicture next to a picture on a beamer but right now the tikzpicture is way below the slide ! Here is my code :

```
\begin{frame}{Frame name}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}{Tikzpicture name}
     %my tikzpicture here
\end{tikzpicture}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
      \includegraphics[width=100px, height=200 px]{PICTURE.jpg}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image: Here's my tikzpicture]

[image: And the slide it gives me after my code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `T` as alignment option for the columns to make sure the very top of the columns is aligned instead of the baseline of the first lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame name}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}{Tikzpicture name}
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=100px, height=200 px]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is it thank you ! Accepting your answer when the website lets me !
If I may ask on more thing, do you know how I could move down the picture since I want to align the basis of both image.

Comment: @PamJeanquita If you want to align the base: `\begin{columns}[b]`